# Vue href binding with static url

Tags: html, vue.js, href

I want to pass a static href + a dynamic part provided through a v-for. In one of the td Something like this. Now, it's reading it as a string.

```
 <td class="">
             **<a class=" " href="https://xxx.yyy.us/org/ `${{currentView["projectName"]}}`"**   
    target="_blank" 
            ><img
              class="inline-block w-10"
              alt=""
              src="../assets/img/mylogo.svg"
              
          /></a>

            
          </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) to bind vue instance data to html attributes.

Shorthand for `v-bind` is `:` which we will use below

```html
<a class=" " :href="'https://xxx.yyy.us/org/' + currentView['projectName']"/>
<!--...-->
</a>
```

Comment: I thought I replied. Yes worked perfectly thanks!